# Building a conditional builder user interface

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I want to make a conditional builder in C# Winform. The general idea is that it allows 'n' number of conditions to be specified in a AND/OR manner. The below UI of Microsoft Flow is how I want to build it.

I am wondering which C# controls should I use that allow me to house 'n' levels of conditionals. Do I have to make/use a custom control here which can be scrollable and allow different groups/rows to be added?

[image: UI Conditional Builder]

Any pointers will be appreciated here.

Comment: I built a similar conditioner builder and used the standard treeview with some aditional functions. But instead för the "+ Add" buttons I used context menues.

Users also wanted to get a better overview of the rather complex condition so I added a text reading the complete condition out in clear text ("State is equal to VA or City is equal to Rickmond or City.." well you get it.